# Too much space between Footer and settings group

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, settings.bundle

I've integrated In-App-Settings into my application. I've added a Footer to my Settings(Root.plist inside of my Settings.bundle).

[image: Root.plist]

I've had some problems with achieving my desired appearance, because the Footer is too far apart from its group (see screenshot below)

[image: Footer is supposed to be directly below group, without gap.]

How do I achieve the "normal" appearance where the Footer comes directly below of its corresponding group? Do I have to modify my Root.plist or does the error lie somewhere else?

Thanks for you help!

EDIT: I don't know if that makes any difference but I've integrated the In-App Settings via the [InAppSettingsKit](http://inappsettingskit.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your Root.plist is a bit incorrect for what you are trying to achieve. Item 3 is causing a new group to be created with no cells and just the footer text which is why there is all that spacing.

You need to delete your Item 3 Dictionary and put the FooterText Key-Value pair in the Item 0 Dictionary to get the footer text directly under your first group